# changed Apple ID password on iMac, need to sync with other system passwords?

Tags: imac, password

I have a very very difficult time remembering passwords. I changed Apple ID password and system required manual entry of other passwords.

**Here's my question**. How do I sync all system passwords (Apple ID, iCloud, keychain, locked screen, un-lock system preferences) so I only have one password and if I change that password, all the other passwords change automatically?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Right now we can only guess what happened, and also only guess what your question might be. Can you please focus your question on one specific issue you are facing, and then go on to ask separate questions for other issues?

Comment: Frankly, with the exception of the last paragraph (as this post currently stands), the rest could/should be deleted!

Comment: So since I can't post this as an awswer since the question's on hold: the answer is you can't, save doing it manually–Apple does not provide a feature to use the same password for your computer login as your Apple ID/iCloud password. You do not need more than two–though.